# Json decoded with python

Tags: python, json, scrapy, web-crawler

(Scrapy)I need help with the next code:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item = MercadoItem()
        #info de producto
        ml_item['nombre'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
        ml_item['web'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/a/@href').extract()
        script_data = response.xpath('string(/html/head/script[3]/text()').extract()
        decoded_data = json.loads(script_data)
        ml_item['datos'] = decoded_data["telephone"]
        ml_item['direccion'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count > 5:
            raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        yield ml_item
```

I use decoded Json for obtain phone number only but the console return me a error
script_data contains the script

> > File "/mercadolibre-scrapy-master/mercado/spiders/spiderq.py", line 88
> >         ml_item['direccion'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
>
> ```
> ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent
> ```

The script is:

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Clínica Dental Castellana 23","description":".TU CLÍNICA DENTAL DE REFERENCIA EN MADRID","telephone":"+34912298837","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"Castellana 23","addressLocality":"MADRID","addressRegion":"Madrid","postalCode":"28003"}}
```

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the line reported by the error, the indentation used to align that line is different from the indentation used for the previous one, for example you may have 4 spaces before and 1 tab after, the may look the same, but they are different for the Python interpreter.

Comment: I fix the indent but now i 've a problem with the imports. "Unable import Scrapy"